# Black outline on PNG fade-in in carousel

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, png, fade, outline

I'm using a feature carousel on my new website - this is a horrible test version but take look and you'll see my problem - http://tradewinds.blendagency.co.uk/carousel/

It works fine in Chrome, FF and IE9 - however in IE8 and IE7, on the fade, an ugly black outline is added to the transparent PNG.

Does anybody know how I can remove the black outline in IE8 and IE7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem with:

```
<style>
img {  
    background: transparent;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF)"; /* IE8 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF);   /* IE6 & 7 */
    zoom: 1;
}
</style>
```

and then wrapping the image in a div, and animating opacity on the div rather than on the img